# comparing floats gives weird behaviour ( > operator)

Tags: objective-c, floating-point

I'm doing a simple comparison between two floating points. When logging however, I came across some unexpected behaviour of this rather basic code:

```
  float balance = self.balance.floatValue;
  float amount = self.amountTextField.text.floatValue;
  if(amount > balance && self.amountTextField.text != nil){
      allowTransfer = NO;
      NSLog(@"allowtransfer: %u", allowTransfer);
  }
```

In my testcase, I used `balance` as a floating point of `47.95`.
All goes well with the comparison until i try `47.96` as a balance and still allowTransfer isn't called, all up to `48.00`

Why is somehow the compiler not considering decimals?

Comment: To which number is it compared?

Comment: I'm comparing the input, which can be anything, to `47.95`

Comment: It's unlikely to be the problem, but you really want the `nil` check to be *first* (ideally before you call `floatValue`).

Comment: @sapi it's just to prevent some odd case. Better to call it than not to call it in my mind.

Comment: @joe How is that relevant to the question?

Comment: FYI - the `>` operator is not a bitwise operator (that would be the `>>` operator).

Comment: @bdv Take some time to study floating point numbers WRT computer programming, that will serve you well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are casting both numbers to an `int` when comparing them, which will truncate both numbers and make it impossible to exactly compare them, it will only compare the integer parts.

To solve it just use float:

```
float balance = self.balance.floatValue;
float amount = self.amountTextField.text.floatValue;
```

Although when dealing with money, you **should not use double or float**. The reason is that they do not support arbitrary precision and you cannot represent exact values (for instance `0.1 + 0.2` as `double` is actually `0.30000000000000004`

Have a look at [NSDecimalNumber](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsdecimalnumber_class/reference/reference.html) for arbitrary precision numbers.

Comment: Thanks! Getting late I suppose.. What do you suggest I use, then?

Comment: A better reason not to use `double` or `float` for currency amounts is that currency fractional amounts are expressed in base 10, whereas `double` and `float` use binary for fractional amounts and are unable to represent 0.01. If you lose 100 dollars because of `double`'s precision, you are dealing with millions of billons of dollars; you can afford it.

Comment: Dear DowVoter: Not providing a reason is **not** helpful. Passive Aggressive much?